# Ensure text remains visible during webfont load is showing even after using `font-display: swap`

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have used `font-display:swap` in my @font-face. But still in google pagespeed I am getting the warning `Ensure text remains visible during webfont load`

here is the code for font.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Cocogoose-Pro-Condensed-Regular;
  src: url(typsnitt/Ttf/Cocogoose-Pro-Condensed-Regular.ttf)
    format('truetype');
  font-display: swap !important;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Cocogoose-Pro-Comp-Light;
  src: url(typsnitt/Ttf/Cocogoose-Pro-Comp-Light.ttf)
    format('truetype');
  font-display: swap !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the link/file exported has included the property `font-display: swap;`, it's not enough if you just add it for yourself in the CSS file

Unless you have the actual font file in your local